# How to install maven-jdocbook-plugin?

Tags: plugins, maven

I want to compile netty, but when I run `mvn install`, it reports this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building The Netty Project 4.0.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-plugin:jar:2.2.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I find the document of [maven-jdocbook-plugin](http://www.jboss.org/maven-jdocbook-plugin/), but I don't find a way to install it. My maven environment is:

```
E:\WORKSPACE_SCALA\netty>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-03-01 01:31:09+0800)
Maven home: E:\java\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_27, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: E:\java\jdk1.6\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

How to install this plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pom for the plugin is missing, you should try to add JBoss plugin repository to your pom.xml (before the </project> tag):

```
 <pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
     <id>JBoss Repo</id>
     <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
     <name>JBoss Repo</name>
   </pluginRepository>   
 </pluginRepositories>
```

You may also need to add it to your artifact repositories :

```
 <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>JBoss Repo</id>
     <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
     <name>JBoss Repo</name>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Comment: The correct repo is now https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss